# How to execute a Powershell script from within diskshadow via the EXEC command?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe

I have a powershell script which backups data from VSS snapshots. I am using [diskshadow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskshadow) to create such snapshots, and thus would like to call the Powershell script from within diskshadow via diskshadow's `EXEC` command.

I have seen [this example](https://bohops.com/2018/03/26/diskshadow-the-return-of-vss-evasion-persistence-and-active-directory-database-extraction/) where even arbitrary `.exe` files are executed from within diskshadow.

But on my system (this is a Windows Server 2019), it is not possible to do that. Please consider the following code / excerpt from an interactive diskshadow session:

```
DISKSHADOW> exec c:\batch\vss\diskshadow-hook.ps1
The command script failed.

DISKSHADOW> exec "powershell.exe" -File c:\batch\vss\diskshadow-hook.ps1

The script file name is not valid.

EXEC <file.cmd>
        Execute a script file on the local machine.
        This command is used to duplicate or restore data as part of
        a backup or restore sequence.
```

Obviously, in contrast to the examples I saw, I can't execute powershell scripts or other executables via diskshadow's `EXEC` command. The only thing I can execute are cmd scripts, which must have the file extension `.cmd`.

Is there a group policy, registry hack or something else which enables the system to not only execute CMD files, but other executable files as well from within diskshadow?

[Note: One "solution" to the problem is to wrap the powershell script into a cmd script, and to call that cmd script from within diskshadow. This works, but it is completely silly IMHO, so I'd like to know whether there is another way.]

Comment: `diskshadow` only supports running `cmd` scripts directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Then the article I linked is wrong, and also the others I saw. Maybe `diskshadow` could run other sorts of executables in previous Windows versions?

Comment: Well they all say "The file can be a cmd script." Nothing says it can be anything else and all the examples only show cmd scripts.

Comment: Maybe a misunderstanding at my side, but in the reference I linked, there is: `EXEC cmd.exe" /c c:\test\evil.exe` (roughly at the end of the first third of the page), and in the sections before, they have screenshots demonstrating how `notepad.exe` is opening when issuing `exec c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe` from within an interactive `diskshadow` session; the same with `calc.exe`. The relevant parts of the screenshots are marked by green borders.

Comment: {shrug} I haven't a clue then.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and your help. For now, I'll just stick with my ugly "solution" (wrap the Powershell script in a CMD script). I'll leave the question as-is for people who have the same problem. Perhaps I'll try to ask that author directly how he did it (but probably not).